# Calling sqlsrv_query() with options, but no params

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

According to the docs, the call to sqlsrv_query() should look like this:

```
mixed sqlsrv_query ( resource $conn , string $sql [, array $params [, array $options ]] )
```

But let's say I" want to do a simple SELECT query with no params, but I do want to pass some options?

This snippet seems to work erratically,

```
$dbh = blah...blah...
$query = 'SELECT * FROM myTable';
$options = array('Scrollable' => SQLSRV_CURSOR_CLIENT_BUFFERED);
$statement = sqlsrv_query($dbh, $query, array(), $options);
```

sometimes returning this error from sqlsrv_error():

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
            (
            [0] => IMSSP
            [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP
            [1] => -14
            [code] => -14
            [2] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query.
            [message] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query.
        )
)
```

What is the correct way to pass options to sqlsrv_query but not parameters?

Per suggestions below, I've also tried `$statement = sqlsrv_query($dbh, $query, null, $options);` with the same results.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `null`, that's how you skip arguments.

Comment: Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/blob/master/source/sqlsrv/conn.cpp#L1116-L1118), it shouldn't matter if you pass `null` vs. an empty array.

Comment: "An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query" tends to happen when `$conn` is not a valid connection.

Comment: Thanks to both AbraCadaver and Sean Bright, but `Álvaro González` solved it.

Apparently my db handle was for some reason going "stale" in the object whose methods was running this query, even though the method was being called from the __construct() (i.e. not being called a long time after the db handle was instantiated).  -- Thank you all!